# Can a new HTML element with a specific class name be created with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I am trying to create an HTML element with a specific class name so when the content is on the DOM the CSS styles can be applied to it. It this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @Mina said , you can use the `element.classList.add("myClass")`.

Answer (score 3):

Just create the element and insert class inside it.

Ex:

```
// inside createElement function you have to type the tag name
const element = document.createElement('div')
element.classList.add('class-name')
// then you need to insert the element inside any element you want ( for example body element )
document.body.appendChild(element)
```

Comment: It worked, Thank you. But I have another problem, I have three more divs with different class names in that single element <li class="todo"> and again the element is being created at the end of the container and i want it come first

Comment: If you want the element comes first ( be the first element ) you need to prepend() method instead of appendChild().

Comment: the prepend works, but like I said is it possible for the other three <divs> with different class names to be in the new element I just created

Comment: If you want to insert other elements inside the element above, simply just create these elements the same way I described above but instead of inserting the inside the body, you have to insert them inside the element.

Comment: `<li class="todo">
        <div class="status"></div>
        <div class="todo_name"><span>Need to charge phone</span></div>
        <div class="delete_btn"><img src="/images/icon-cross.svg" alt=""></div</li>`

Comment: If these elements already exist in your HTML, and you don't need to create them. Just select them with anyway you want, for example document.getElementById or document.getElementsByClassName, and then use appendTo() or prependTo() methods.

Comment: Sorry to bother you please, Can you please give a use case to this so I'd be able to do that.

Comment: Just to be on the correct path, Are these elements that you want to insert inside the created element, already exist in the HTML, or do you want to create them too?

Comment: They already exist. Or is there a way I can please show you what my code looks like so you can just see what I am talking about

Comment: Sure, please write your code in jsfiddle and share it. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Here it is sir, https://jsfiddle.net/official_abdultech/uekzwqby/

Comment: So I can let you know what problems i Have sir 
 https://jsfiddle.net/official_abdultech/uekzwqby/#&togetherjs=48ug0Ga5ry

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for. https://jsfiddle.net/mena234/hscu04eb/8/

Comment: cloneNode(true) will clone the element with all it's children and content, and then initialize the text inside it with the text of the input, then prepend it in the todoContainer element. ( you don't need to createElement or add class to it, the easiest way to use clone )